# Django webapp seems to ignore that it was logged in

Tags: ios, django, ipad, session

I am currently developing a Django webapp that will be launched from the homescreen on my clients iPads. Each user on the app needs to log in once, and the session should persist for months. Closing the browsers and rebooting the devices should not make any difference. I have previously done this in PHP and those projects remain to work properly ever since iOS 8.

Unfortunately this now only works on the desktop and 'normal' Safari on the iPad. Launching the webapp from the homescreen forces a login, which I perform. When I check the cookie that is set on the iPad (through the Safari debugger on the Mac) I can see that the cookie is set to expire one year from now. This confirms that the `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` variable from our config is working properly:

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 31556928  # one year
```

Dumping the session data for the session ID in my cookies shows the same values for `_auth_user_id` and `_auth_user_hash`. These values do not change when I login for a second, third or fourth time after forcefully killing the webapp on the iPad.

For clarity, this is the list of packages that I use in the projects virtualenv:

```
Django (1.8.7)
django-appconf (1.0.1)
django-ckeditor (5.0.2)
django-compressor (1.6)
django-extensions (1.6.1)
django-filer (0.9.12)
django-flat-theme (1.1.3)
django-hvad (1.4.0)
django-mptt (0.8.0)
django-multiselectfield (0.1.3)
django-polymorphic (0.7.2)
django-rosetta (0.7.8)
djrill (2.0)
docopt (0.4.0)
easy-thumbnails (2.2)
ecdsa (0.13)
Fabric (1.10.2)
feedparser (5.2.1)
FeinCMS (1.11.4)
mandrill (1.0.57)
microsofttranslator (0.7)
MySQL-python (1.2.5)
paramiko (1.16.0)
path.py (8.1.2)
Pillow (2.6.1)
pip (8.0.2)
polib (1.0.7)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pytz (2015.7)
requests (2.9.1)
setuptools (11.0)
six (1.10.0)
solid-i18n (1.1.1)
Unidecode (0.4.18)
```

Simply setting the cookie to expire in the future, which solved the problem in PHP, does not work for the Django project. Is there somebody who has run into this problem before?

**Solved! (2016-01-31)**

I don't know if I should feel stupid or not, but the issue is solved. I was using the `@login_required` decorator on the homepage view. Loading the webapp from a blank/new session would redirect the homepage (/) to `<domain>/login/?next=/`. So, when opening the webapp in Safari and adding it to the homescreen, would also set webapp url to `<domain>/login/?next=/`. But, this page **always** shows the loginform, regardless if you are logged in already. I wrongfully assumed that it would redirect you to the page that was set in the `next` variable. But since a homescreenapp without a manifest file always reloads the URL that it was saved with, you would always see the loginform.

I now solved the problem by removing the login_required decorator from view and adding a check if the user is authenticated:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():

    ctx = {}
    response = render(request, 'registration/login.html', ctx)
    return response

else:

    # normal flow
```

I can now use the webapp without logging in, even after closing it from the multitask window.

Alternatively, you could log in and add the webapp to the homescreen afterwards.

Comment: Having the same problem here. Please let me know if you have found a way around it.

Comment: thanks, @VTe, but as it turns up my problem was other. Cookie.js (which I'm using to save some user prefs) is apparently overwriting the django session cookie on Safari iOS. I will file a bug to Cookie.js when I find the time.